Are Daksha and Aditi deities? Who is Asridh?
This chapter of Rig Veda says to invoke the deities:-

We invoke them with an ancient text, Bhaga, Mitra, Aditi, Dakṣa, Asridh, Aryaman, Varuṇa, Soma, the Aśvins; and may the gracious Sarasvatī grant us happiness.”

Aditi and Daksha are said to invoked. Most of us know them. But it is interseting for learning them as deities, so my question is, Are Daksha and Aditi deities? Are the hymns and worship methods for them available in scripture?

At the same time, I see the name 'Asridh' in the list of these deities from the abobe verse. We should know about the other deities, but who is this Asridh? Does any other scriptures mention about Asridh?

In some Vedic Yajnas they might have offerings to be made to them but they are not worshipped in mainstream tradition anywhere else .. Prajapati is invoked in any Vedic homa and he gets the first offering and Daksha is a Prajapati.

Sayanacharya thinks that Asridh refers to the Marudgana
